# What namespace is required for WebAPI in this "www.asp.net" tutorial?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, intellisense

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations), and am getting stuck trying to code this method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
{
    item = repository.Add(item);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

    string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

- What namespace is the `Request` object?    Is it the same thing as HTTPRequest?  If so then why won't Intellisense help me complete it?  (I get unknown method)
- What namespace is the `URL.Link` object/method?

I searched for these objects in Bing and Google but can't find anything that isn't related to Voice/SIP which has nothing to do with WepAPI

Comment: `Request` isn't an object, it's a property on an `ApiController`. Same for `Url`. Did you put the method inside of the Web API controller that you created in the 'Adding a Web API Controller' step?

Comment: @DeanWard You found it!  Thanks for helping out a N00b!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `System.Net.Http`, this should be all you need.

You can go and [download the project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASP-NET-Web-API-Tutorial-c4761894), it might be worth doing this for reference.

Also, a good tool for helping with this type of issue and a lot more with development is [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).